# Can't create VM with virt-install on Debian wheezy

Tags: port, vnc, virt-install, debian-wheezy

Cant find any answers anywhere so here goes.

I am trying to CREATE a new virtual machine using the virt-install command from a console on a Debian wheezy install.

I keep getting the following output:

```
Starting install...
ERROR    internal error process exited while connecting to monitor: char device redirected to /dev/pts/1
inet_listen_opts: bind(ipv4,127.0.0.1,5951): Cannot assign requested address
inet_listen_opts: FAILED
```

I assumed that the port (5951 in this case) was being used judging by the error message and other sites I visited for an answer, but the same error occurs whatever number I use for the port. I cant see that port being listened upon in netstat either.

Anyone have any ideas what may be wrong?

Comment: Is your `lo` interface up?

Comment: You solved it Michael nice one :) If you add that as an answer, I'll make it the accepted answer and give you the points.

Comment: Done :) Glad to hear it's fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to make sure your `lo` interface is up and running properly.